# Replay subject subscription behaviour

Tags: system.reactive

The following code works as expected but I am puzzled by the way it behaves when I uncomment the line 'o.OnCompleted();'

The code joins all subscribers to the result of a single long operation and caches the result for further subscribers for 2 seconds. Any subscription after this time starts the process again.

Subscriptions will come from other threads (simulated with the thread pool).

```
        var obs = Observable.Create((IObserver<Guid> o) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start");
            Thread.Sleep(1000); // process
            Console.WriteLine("End");
            o.OnNext(Guid.NewGuid());
            //o.OnCompleted(); // <-- uncomment this
            return Disposable.Empty;
        })
        .Replay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
        .RefCount()
        .Take(1);

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
        {
            // simulate request from threadpool
            obs.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"1: {x}"), () => Console.WriteLine($"1: complete"));
        });

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
        {
            obs.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"2: {x}"), () => Console.WriteLine($"2: complete"));
        });

        Thread.Sleep(4000);

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
        {
            obs.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"3: {x}"), () => Console.WriteLine($"3: complete"));
        });
```

Here is the result:

```
Start
End
1: 255BEFDC-2F14-40AD-AE77-2B005C5A3AA9
2: 255BEFDC-2F14-40AD-AE77-2B005C5A3AA9
1: complete
2: complete
Start
End
3: 1214DC63-F688-475A-9CB7-C3784054A4AC
3: complete
```

The odd behaviour is if I uncomment the line 'o.OnCompleted()' the result changes to this:

```
Start
End
1: 255BEFDC-2F14-40AD-AE77-2B005C5A3AA9
2: 255BEFDC-2F14-40AD-AE77-2B005C5A3AA9
1: complete
2: complete
Start
End
3: complete
```

The 3rd subscriber causes another subscription to the root observable but the result is missing. It appears the ReplaySubject caches the result of the previous observable having completed but still causes a new subscription. This seems unintuitive. I would like to understand why it doesn't work.

Note: I originially tried this using Defer instead of Create which had the same result as the second run above (for obvious reasons).

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `Replay`/`RefCount` pair you create an observable that shares a common subscription to the source observable.

From the source:

> Returns a connectable observable sequence that shares a single subscription to the underlying sequence replaying all notifications.

Now, it's important to remember that an observable produces a series of zero or more values, followed by either a complete or error signal. It cannot produce values after a complete or error is produced.

Since you are sharing a common subscription to the source and if your source producing a complete then it cannot produce more values. So when you call `o.OnCompleted()` then you're doing exactly that.

Also, as a side-note, you should avoid ever writing `return Disposable.Empty;` inside a `Create`. It means you're creating an observable than can complete before the subscription has returned and that can lead to race conditions.

The way to write your code without it is:

```
var obs =
    Observable
        .Defer(() => Observable.Return(Guid.NewGuid()).Concat(Observable.Never<Guid>()))
        .Replay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0))
        .RefCount()
        .Take(1);
```

But this is the same as not calling `o.OnCompleted()`.

Comment: I think I need to rephrase my question: If the Replay has a single subscription to the Observable, why is the subscription action executed again when there is a subscription after the timeout?

Comment: Regarding the use of 'Disposable.Empty' I took the advice from here: http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/20_Disposables.html

Comment: @DavidJ - There's obviously a mechanism that is resubscribing - the underlying call to `Replay` is calling `source.Multicast(new ReplaySubject<TSource>(window));` so you'd have to trace down that rabbit hole to see where it leads.

Comment: @DavidJ - The link doesn't offer advice on when should you use `Disposable.Empty`, just what circumstance that you could. My suggestion is that you avoid it in 99.99% of all cases. It'll lead to bad things.

Comment: I'm looking at the code for Observable.Create now. It seem that, no matter what I return, the return value will be wrapped in a Disposable. If I return 'null' then it is changed to Disposable.Empty. If I return an Action then it is wrapped in Disposable.Create - ergo if I return a no-op action it is the same as returning Disposable.Empty.

Comment: @DavidJ - The issue is that you're creating a possible race condition. You should avoid `Disposable.Empty` at almost all cost.

Comment: What should I return instead?

Comment: @DavidJ - The query I wrote in my answer is the kind of thing you should do. Always try to express the query in terms of existing operators. You should try to restrict the use of `Create` to when you need to introduce state.